# Limit of product of kth roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

For $n\geq 1$ , let $$A(n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+\frac{k}{n})^\frac{1}{k}.$$ I'd like to determine $$ \lim_{n->\infty} A(n).$$ Taking logarithms and using the following crude  bound gives $$\log(A(n))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\log(1+\frac{k}{n}) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\log(1+\frac{k}{n}).$$ By interpreting this latter sum as a Riemann sum for $\log(1+x)$ on $[0,1]$, we see that the desired limit is at least $4/e$. However, this lower bound is far from sharp and is clearly not strong enough to determine the actual limit. Appreciate if someone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: A very closely related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4074144) asked recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log A(n)$ is the sequence of Riemann sums of $$\int_0^1 x^{-1}\log(1+x)dx= \int_0^1 \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{m+1} }mx^{m-1}dx$$
What do you get next?