# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^{n}[1+(r/n)^2]^{1/r}$ by expressing it as a definite integral

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I have been asked to find the limit of the following series by expressing it as definite integral:

> If $na=1$ always and $n$ tends to infinity, find the limiting value
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\prod_{r=1}^{n}[1+(ra)^2]^{1/r}\right)$$

The answer given is $\exp\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}\right)$.

I took the log of both sides and set up my integral as $$\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x^2)dx$$

But my answer came out wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $a$, and why does it not show up in the answer?

Comment: I think a=1/n as it is given that an=1 always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $ na = 1$ we can write the product as $\displaystyle \mathcal{P} := \prod_{r=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)^{1/r}.$

Then taking logs and using the continuity of logs

\begin{align} \log(\mathcal P) & = 
\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{r=1}^n\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)^{1/r}\right)
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\prod_{r=1}^n\left(1+\frac {r^2}{ n^2}\right)^{1/r}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1r\log\left(1+ \frac {r^2}{ n^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n}{r}  \log\left(1+ \frac {r^2}{ n^2}\right)\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1x\log(1+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)(2k+2)} \\& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\\& = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{24}.
\end{align}

Therefore $\displaystyle \mathcal P = \exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{24}\right).$

Comment: Thank you so much. But I did not understand sixth step. Can you please explain it?

Comment: We use the Taylor series of $\log(1+t)$, with $t = x^2$ and then divide by $x$. Or do you mean the step before?

Comment: OK! so you used Taylor series of log(1+t). Got it! Thanks again